# Accessing AddInContent PDF Document

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in, pdf

I'm converting a COM Extension to an Add-In.  The old extension installed a PDF alongside the .dll and an Command in the extension start the PDF Viewer process (using Process.Start(pdflocation).

I'm running into trouble duplicating this with the Add-In structure.

In Visual Studio I have my PDF file included in a 'Resources' folder I made.  I've got the PDF's Build Action set to AddInContent. Where can I find this file after the Add-In is deployed?

I used `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;` to see that the .dll file is located in `C:\Users\myuseraccount\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.2\AssemblyCache\{<AddIn GUID>}\` but I do not see my Resources directory here (or even the Images directory containing the images that my Add-In buttons and tools use)

So like the title states... How do I access files in an Add-In that have a Build Type of AddInContent?

Answer (score 1):

Aha!  I figured it out.

What I had to do was set the PDF's 'Build Action' to 'Content' and then set 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Always'.

More information here: [Advanced add-in concepts / File Structure](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#File)

Just have to RTFM I guess ;)